# How to approach prediction of new observations with incomplete data from model built from complete data

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data, boosting

I currently have a gradient boosting model that uses the `gbm` package in R that classifies observations at the end of a year. Daily behaviors are logged for each observation (with most of them zero). The model is built on observations which have a year's worth of complete data and performs well out of sample.

For illustrative purposes, assume the complete data look like this:

```
id day1 day2 day3 day4 day5, ..., day365
 1    1    1    2    0    0, ...,      0
 2    3    0    1    0    0, ...,      0
 3    1    1    2    0    0, ...,      0
 4    1    0    0    0    0, ...,      1
```

However, I want to predict the probability of each class for new individuals who have not yet been in the sampling frame for a year. Thus, all of the days past the present day will be NA. This precludes the use of many algorithms, but treating them as 0s also implies having more information than I actually have.

What is the best way to treat the unobserved, but observable missing data when making predictions? I will not be re-estimating the model on a daily basis but rather using the model fit from the existing training set.